# Child theme CSS not applying to element

Tags: css, child-theme

I'm working on a child theme for a client and I have a few overriding styles. However, they're not even showing up in the Chrome inspector.

For example if you go to this page: http://vintageaudioswap.com/sign-up-login and click on "Sign up", I'm trying to override the header background-color. Look at my CSS file here: http://vintageaudioswap.com/wp-content/themes/javo-directory-child/style.css?ver=1.0
Last line.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is happening on more than just this page.

Comment: Look at line 295 of your child theme css. There is an extra "{" after "-webkit-border-radius: 3px;"....Remove that  "{" and your css is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the marked '{' from  line 295 of your child theme styles.css file. Check the bellow image to be sure what to remove.

[image: Remove the marked '{' from line 295 of your child theme css.]

Comment: That was it! Thanks man. Been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 3):

This is your issue. Check php code because I saw it in html inspect :)
[image]

Comment: this is not the reason that stopped partial css loading properly. Please check my comment to the actual question.

Comment: After resolve that issue then you can check your css.
1 error here http://prntscr.com/hutum0
Just remove it :)